# WPF - Size rectangle by its ImageBrush opacity mask

Tags: wpf, opacity, mask, sizing, imagebrush

I have a rectangle which has an ImageBrush opacity mask (basically a coloured icon).

This is my current code:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black">
  <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Path/To/Icon.png"/>
  </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

This produces no result without setting a fixed width and height for the rectangle. Is it possible to size the rectangle according to the ImageBrush image size?

Thanks for your help. Sorry if this is a silly question, I am still learning WPF.

**Edit**: To clarify, what I am trying to achieve is for the rectangle to behave same as this:

```
<Image Source="/Path/To/Icon.png"/>
```

It should be sized according to the dimensions of the image source file.

Answer (score 0):

`Stretch="None"` keep image size. Rectangle with binding `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` resize from `ImageBrush` size. Result is same if we don't use both. On both case rectangle resize to true ImageBrush size. Hope I understand your problem.

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Path/To/Icon.png" x:Name="image" Stretch="None">
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this does not seem to solve my problem. I have edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Rectangle Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\neeraj\Pictures\Img1.jpg" x:Name="image" Stretch="None">
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Try this snippet. I am not sure why you wanted the fill black. If idea was to have a Black surrounding, use Background="Black" on the outer Grid.